# Qualité de vie or qualité de LA vie?

Tags: grammaire, articles

In my grammar book I had to complete the missing articles in the following exercise:

*Les problèmes de circulation, les questions de société, le monde du sport, la qualité de **la** vie : tous les sujets de conversation sont passionnant pour Roger.*

Why is it *de **la** vie* here? My understanding was that *la qualité de vie* was the English translation of "quality of life". Is it because it's the quality of Roger's life, or of those that he is talking to?

Are there other examples like this where *la* and *de la* are both accepted depending on the context?

For example, *taux de chômage* - but *taux de la chômage* to state the unemployment rate in a specific place appears incorrect... why is this the case?

Any light that can be shed on this would be greatly appreciated, I've been racking my brain and trying to find the answer via Google but to no avail!

Comment: Good question. Both are said. By the way it's *le taux du chômage* (chômage being masculine). 
Just out of curiosity: were you given a choice of articles to choose from and if you were, was Ø (Zero article) a possible choice?

Comment: Yes the instructions were: *du, de la, de l' or de + articles définis ou indéfinis si c'est nécessaire*

Comment: While we often speak of "les chiffres du chômage" , when speaking of "taux", we always use "de": taux de chômage, taux de pauvreté, taux d'alphabétisation,...

Answer (score 1):

I started as a comment but it got too long, unfortunately I can't give you a complete satisfying answer except that both are said: *qualité de la vie* and *qualité de vie*.

To start with I'd say I would have said like you *qualité de vie* in the exercise (I'm 100 % French born and bred in case you wonder). Considering the enumeration in the sentence I consider it to be understood as the English "quality of life" (i.e. in general). Then I'll just point to a few random thoughts that certainly need expanding.

- *Qualité de vie* could be the scientific concept, something that can be measured through statistics, polls, etc.
- *Qualité de la vie* could be more empirical, or philosophical.
- Another more down to earth thought has crossed my mind: the person who made the exercise absolutely wanted  the students to fill in all the blanks and did not even think there could be two possibilities.

I've had a look at the article [Qualité de vie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualit%C3%A9_de_vie) in wikipedia, noticed they use indifferently *qualité de la vie* and *qualité de vie*.

> L'Organisation mondiale de la santé définit en 1994 la qualité de la vie comme...

> Les chercheurs s’accordent tout de même à considérer la qualité de vie comme un concept multidimensionnel ...

Google books returns about the same amount of [*qualité de vie*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22qualit%C3%A9+de+vie%22&hl=fr&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4vNCU4dvxAhXoz4UKHQu0BjkQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1860&bih=909)  as of [*qualité de la vie*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22qualit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20vie%22).

---

There would be instances of more precise contexts where I would still hesitate between the two:

- La qualité de (la) vie à Paris est meilleure qu'à la campagne.

But no hesitation for:

- La qualité de la vie de nos parents n'était pas aussi bonne que la nôtre.
  Because in this last sentence I have used *nos parents* and *la nôtre* to define *qualité de vie*. And it seems to me more personal than just *à Paris* vs *à la campagne*.

Comment: Thank you. This helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

As concerns "circulation", both are acceptable. As shows the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+probl%C3%A8mes+de+circulation%2Cles+probl%C3%A8mes+de+la++circulation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20probl%C3%A8mes%20de%20circulation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20probl%C3%A8mes%20de%20la%20circulation%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cles%20probl%C3%A8mes%20de%20circulation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20probl%C3%A8mes%20de%20la%20circulation%3B%2Cc0) below until the mid sixties in the past century both were used with equal frequency; then, as the phrase with the definite article became rather rare that without remained in comparatively frequent use.

[image]

It can be verified [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20probl%C3%A8mes%20de%20la%20circulation%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20probl%C3%A8mes%20de%20circulation%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) that the usage is the correct one (same meaning of "circulation").

As pertains to "société", the matter is different; the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+questions+de+soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%2Cles+questions+de+la+soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20questions%20de%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20questions%20de%20la%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cles%20questions%20de%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20questions%20de%20la%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) below shows that the phrase containing the article is relatively rare at all times.

[image]

This is so because the meaning of "société" is not the same when the article is used; in that case the article is not the definite article that is used in French with nouns (freedom/la liberté, business/les affaires, time/le temps,…) but it is the article used as a "local" determinative in expressions where "société" does not mean "société des êtres humains d'un pays" at large; when this meaning is restricted (société contemporaine) then the article is used (les questions de *la* société contemporaine). This can be verified on this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20questions%20de%20la%20soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

"Le monde de sport" is not said at all ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+monde+du+sport%2Cle+monde+de+sport&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20monde%20du%20sport%3B%2Cc0)). This case stands in opposition to the others and it will be taken up again at the end.

The third case is similar to the first; as "qualité de la vie" began to be used less and less, "qualité de vie" became more frequent ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+qualit%C3%A9+de+la+vie%2Cla+qualit%C3%A9+de+vie&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20qualit%C3%A9%20de%20la%20vie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20qualit%C3%A9%20de%20vie%3B%2Cc0)).

[image]

You can see that both can be used but much more common is the phrase without the article. In my opinion, you can still say "qualité de la vie".

"Taux de la chômage" is incorrect on two counts: "chômage" is masculine, and so it should be "taux *du* chômage" ("taux *de le* chômage", not correct, but that is the equivalent form in terms of meaning), and then this last form, even if correct grammatically, is not used at all ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taux+de+chom%C3%A2ge%2Ctaux+du+chom%C3%A2ge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaux%20de%20chom%C3%A2ge%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctaux%20de%20chom%C3%A2ge%3B%2Cc0)).

What is to be retained concerning cases "1", "2" and "4" is there is no grammatical rule involved; this is simply a matter of usage. In fact it shows a tendency towards two means of determination of nouns in French for a single context, the traditional one (preposition of the definite article) and the  zero article one. That is about all that can be said grammar-wise.

Getting back to "monde du sport", it is interesting to notice that "monde de sport" is not said at all, whereas "questions *de* circulation", "problèmes *de* société" and "taux *de* chômage" all occur. This is to be sought in the semantics of "de".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de))
> **I.** − *De* prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
> **C.** − *De* marque une circonstance qui précise (et parfois conditionne) une modalité d'existence ou d'action.
> **5.** La modalité est une appartenance.
> **a)** Possession, dépendance.
> − [Le compl. déterminatif est déterminé]
> **α)** [Le possesseur est une pers., un groupe ou un être animé déterminé.]
> **de + subst. concr. (nom propre ou nom commun)**.
> ♦  Elle est là, dans la chambre de Bébé, avec Madeleine (H. Bataille, Maman Colibri,1904, IV, 8, p. 30)
> ♦ Vous décider à envoyer ma sœur à Mirosménil, ou même à Limeuil, prendre l'air du printemps et boire le lait **de nos** vaches. (Bernanos, Dialog. Carm.,1948, 1ertabl., 1, p. 1572)
> ♦ Nos amis recueillaient les grandes paroles simples **de leur** concierge, **du** facteur, **du** plombier, et nous les rapportaient (Sartre, Mots,1964, p. 174)
> ♦ Ne sommes-nous pas, d'ailleurs, dans le pays **des** chevaliers **de la** Table ronde, dans la contrée **des** fées, dans la patrie **de** Merlin, au berceau mythologique **des** épopées disparues? (Flaubert, Par les champs et par les grèves,1848, p. 355)
> ♦ Des bols de ce perpétuel lait de malade apparurent aussi dans les mains **de** Christine, entre ses deux mains à lui, sur sa table de nuit, exactement comme pour sa mère. Mais on lui présentait ce lait froid, presque glacé. Malègue, Augustin,t. 2, 1933, p. 379.

It can be seen from the examples that for proper nouns "*de*" is used but for all others "de + < definite article or other determiner >" is the form in use. This is characteristic of the semantic relation of belonging.

- chambre *de Bébé* —  which belongs to Bébé"
- lait *de nos vaches*  — the cows that belong to us
- paroles *de leur concierge, du facteur, du plombier* — words that belong to the caretaker, the postman, etc. ie that are theirs as having been said by them, or in other terms, words that are being called theirs because they said them
- …

Notice "lait de malade" (no article). "Le monde du sport" has to be interpreted as "le monde qui appartient au sport" (although this is rather awkward).

The relations to be read into "de" as regards "problème de circulation" and "questions de société" are related to one another: "concerned with", "treating of".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de))
> **I.** − De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
> **B.** − De marque la condition préalable d'un procès ou du résultat d'un procès matériel ou moral.
> **5.** [La condition préalable est la matière d'un propos] Dire qqc. de qqn; instruire qqn d'une affaire; remercier qqn de qqc., de faire qqc. (cf. aussi la cause).
> − De signifie « quant à », « en ce qui concerne », « au sujet de », « à propos de », « pour ce qui est de », « relativement à ».
> **c)** Subst. + de. De signifie « qui traite de ».
> − [Dans le domaine de la pensée]
> ♦ Je suis au collège. J'ai quinze ans. Je résous avec patience mon problème **de** géométrie (Saint-Exup., Pilote guerre,1942, p. 265)

In this case there is often no article with no alternative of using it.

- un sujet de philosophie, une pièce de théâtre, un livre de musique, un article de science médicale, un théorème de mathématique,

"Taux de chômage" is explained by a clear-cut usage found in the TLFi. The stipulation of the construction makes precise that there must be some determination (Subst. désignant la qualité + de + subst. déterminé).

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de))
> **I.** − *De* prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
> **C.** − *De* marque une circonstance qui précise (et parfois conditionne) une modalité d'existence ou d'action.
> **5.** La modalité est une appartenance.
> **b)** Qualité, détermination, qualification, caractérisation.
> − [Le compl. introduit par de a une valeur attributive].
> **α)** Subst. désignant la qualité + de + subst. déterminé.
> Subst. abstr.
> ♦ L'immensité **de la** mer (transpos. de *la mer est immense*); cette moiteur **de l** 'air; cette pureté **du** silence; la fermeté **du** ton.
> ♦  Ce ne sont pas les idées seules qui nous séparent (...) qui suffisent à nous rapprocher, mais une certaine qualité **du** regard que nous fixons sur autrui (Mauriac, Journal 3,1940, p. 210)
> J'ai vraiment admiré, à plus d'une reprise, la présence d'esprit **du** président et sa connaissance de chaque affaire; l'urgence **de ses** interrogatoires; la fermeté et la modération **de l** 'accusation; la densité **des** plaidoiries, et l'absence de vaine éloquence; enfin l'attention **des** jurés. Gide, Souvenirs de la Cour d'assises,1913, p. 619.

It is clear that "qualité de la vie" fits this latter definition; however, the initial agreement of actual usage with this definition has seen a rapid erosion, as can be seen in the ngram.

Comment: 1. How did you manage to answer to a closed question? 2. *Taux de chomâge* is unrelated to *âge*.

Comment: 1. This is possibly due to the fact that the answer was begun before the time of closing, otherwise I don't know.